# Mendota fire place

Tags: fireplace

I have a new Mendota fv34 arch.just turned the gas back on and put the batteries back in the remote and synced it.the pilot will light but not the burners

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Have you read through [the installation instructions](https://mendotahearth.com/pdfs/manuals/85-03-01106-E%20FV34%20ARCH%20FIREPLACE%20INSTALLATION%20AND%20OPERATING%20INSTRUCTIONS%200219.pdf)?  And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: You need to purge the air out of the pipes. This may take quite a while I usually use a flame source to heat the thermocouple and burn any gas that might be mixed with air, once I have a flame I hold the pilot for up to a minute and turn on then it usually works from that point if the thermocouple is good.